# Using Permutations in Java for solving an equation

Tags: java, permutation, equation, backtracking, brute-force

For a given problem I am granted with two numbers that will sum to a certain result in this way:

```
num1 + num2 = result
```

However these numbers will be "coded", so, for example, an input may be:

```
ab + bc = acd
```

The numbers can have any length up to 9 digits.

My task is to create an efficient method to find how many possible solutions each input has or if it is impossible.

I have tackled this issue by creating a class called Number (in java), that has a letter (char type) and a numeric value (int) and then I converted each number to an array of this new class Number, so I can easily check their current values.

However I'm not so sure how to approach this backtracking issue.

I am aware that I should start comparing the units from number1 and number2, then the tens, and so on, in each "level" selecting only the cases in which the sum will be logical, so for example in the above example for the units b=2 and c= 3 it would only make sense if d=5, and I could discard all the other cases in which d!= 5 for those two preexisting values.

I am told it is possible to cover all these permutations using only two cycles: One for cyclcing through the possible numbers [0 to 9] and one to cover all the letters/variables, but I don't quite understand how it could be done!

If I had to imagine it I guess I could think of it as

```
for cycle ( through "columns" from the rightmost up to the leftmost column of the shortest number)
  for cycle( for numbers 0 to 9?)
```

but still I can't wrap my head around this approach to the subject, or how I could tackle this with recursion instead, all help to improve my understanding is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is your inputs? What is your output? your problem is not clear. You say a number can be 9 digits, is it means `a` can be `1236548`?? Or a letter is equal to a digit?

Comment: @majid hajibaba: Each letter is a single digit.  An equation can have up to nine letters in each operand or sum.  To the OP: I've used brute force to solve this type of problem in the past because the equation can have at most 10 different letters representing 0 - 9 and at most 27 total letters (three 10 ^ 9 integers).  Nested loops with tiny numbers is fast.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one algorithm that should work.

Let's take your example equation:

```
ab + bc = acd
```

1. Determine the number of unique characters in the equation.  In your example, that would be four (a, b, c, d).
2. In order to iterate through all of the possibilities, we're going to set up a loop.  The minimum value of this loop is 10 ^ 3 or 1,000. The maximum value of this loop is 10 ^ 4 or 10,000.  The number of unique characters in the equation determines the powers of 10 you'll use.  The maximum maximum is 10 ^ 10 which is bigger than an `int`.  A `long` would work.
3. Inside the iteration, split the index into N digits.  In your example, that would be 4 digits.  Since we're iterating from 1,000 to 9,999 inclusive (10,000 excluded) all of the index values will have 4 digits.
4. Check to make sure the N digits are unique.  No duplicates.  This will eliminate most of the index values at the start.
5. Substitute the digits into the equation and check to see if the equation is valid.  If so, save the equation in a `List<String>`.
6. Output the `List` values or no solution found after completing the iteration.